# What is this stubbed out copper line?

Tags: plumbing

I removed an old shower tub combo and discovered a stubbed out pipe coming through the floor. What is it? Is it an old drain pipe or old incoming pipe[image]

Comment: Copper is nearly always supply. Old drains before pvc were typically cast iron.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Has been some pictures on here of old copper looking big drain pipes.  Guess they were for rich folks homes.

Answer (score 2):

Too small for a drain pipe, probably an old water pipe.

Would be nice to find where it comes from, and disable it at source/beginning, with a proper cap.

Will probably want to keep it easy to look at, incase it ever starts leaking,if not removed, no burying it in cement/under a expensive floor.

To test if it still connected to house water, turn off water, cut pipe for cap, turn on water.  If no water probably has been disconnected somewhere else.  If water, add cap or shut off valve for future work.

Comment: Consider if water comes out to put a valve on it, that will make using it later much easier.